How to easily instantiate grandchild classes from numerous child classes which each have a constant N number of subclasses?
As an example, say I've got a class Letters, which is the parent to 26 classes A, B, C... Z, which are each in turn parent to N=2 classes UpperA, LowerA, UpperB, LowerB, etc.
I want to define the following function in Letters
def LetterFactory(font: str, letter: str, lettercase: str):
  match letter:
    case 'A':
      if lettercase == 'upper':
        return UpperA(font)
      elif lettercase == 'lower':
        return LowerA(font)
    case 'B':
       ...

Is there a way for me avoid having to write out if lettercase 52 times?
Two solutions I've thought of so far both seemed suboptimal:

Use a dictionary, e.g.
alphabet = {
"A" : {
  "upper" : UpperA,
  "lower" : LowerA
},
"B" : {
...



which still has the same issue of copypasting 26 times.

Select the class based on class naming pattern
def LetterFactory(font: str, letter: str, lettercase: str):
    class_name = lettercase + letter
    letter_class = globals()[class_name]
    return letter_class(font)



which is very ugly
Is there a better solution?

Option 2 will work and is concise. After all, globals() merely returns a dictionary so it's really no different to writing your own dictionary / map

I don't think you should have classes that differ by some scalar, as if you have a list of classes along a dimension. In my opinion this dimension should be incorporated in the same class. Can you find a scenario where this really would be useful?

So define two arrays of function references:
uppers = [UpperA, UpperB ...]  // function references
lowers = [LowerA, LowerB ...]

And your function becomes, essentially:
letterFactory(font, letter, letterCase)
    if (letterCase == "upper")
        return uppers[letter](font)
    else
        return lowers[letter](font)

I'm not a Python programmer, so I can't show you the exact syntax, but the idea of a dispatch table is pretty common. You'll have to do some kind of conversion of the letter so you can index into the array. A typical way is to convert the letter to an integer and then subtract the value of 'A' to make it 0-based.
